# Focus on Input when Bootstrap Modal closes

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, focus

After a blur event on an input field "bootbox1", I want to use  a Bootstrap Modal for an message, after the modal closes the focus would go to the input field "bootbox2". But the input field does not get focus.

What am I doing wrong?

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/barryit99/Lqtuykr2/2/)

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="bootbox" />
<input type="text" id="bootbox2" />
<div id="myModal" class="modal fade">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <!-- dialog body -->
        <div class="modal-body">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>Hello world!</div>
        <!-- dialog buttons -->
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS

```
$('#bootbox').on('blur', function checkSelection(e) {
  $("#myModal").on("show", function () { // wire up the OK button to dismiss the modal when shown
    $("#myModal a.btn").on("click", function (e) {
        console.log("button pressed"); // just as an example...
        $("#myModal").modal('hide');
        $('#bootbox2').focus();
        // dismiss the dialog
    });
  });

  $("#myModal").on("hide", function () { // remove the event listeners when the dialog is dismissed
    $("#myModal a.btn").off("click");
    $('#bootbox2').focus();
  });

  $("#myModal").on("hidden", function () { // remove the actual elements from the DOM when fully hidden
    $("#myModal").remove();
  });

  $("#myModal").modal({ // wire up the actual modal functionality and show the dialog
    "backdrop": "static",
        "keyboard": true,
        "show": true // ensure the modal is shown immediately
  });

});

//this works
$('#bootbox2').on('blur', function checkSelection(e) {
  $('#bootbox').focus();
});
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to wait for the `hidden.bs.modal` event to fire, not the `hide.bs.modal`.

According to the [Bootstrap Docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals-events) for the event `hide.bs.modal`

> This event is fired immediately when the hide instance method has been
>   called.

Whereas `hidden.bs.modal`

> This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the
>   user (will wait for CSS transitions to complete).

Since your `focus` is being called before the overlay has been removed the input cannot take the keyboard focus yet.